# Run ActiveMQ Artemis on my docker specifically on mac M1

Tags: docker, docker-compose, activemq-artemis

I am trying to run ActiveMQ Artemis on my docker but i have been receiving many errors trying to get this to work. I am not sure if it is something to do with my yml file or not.

This the command i am using:
`docker-compose up`

This is my yml file:

```
version: '2'

services:

  artemis:
    image: quay.io/artemiscloud/activemq-artemis-broker
    ports:
      - "8161:8161"
      - "61616:61616"
      - "5672:5672"
    environment:
       ARTEMIS_USERNAME: "admin"
       ARTEMIS_PASSWORD: "admin"
    networks:
      - amqp-quickstart-network
networks:
  amqp-quickstart-network:
```

I am receiving this error and not sure how to work around this.

```
Attaching to infrastructure-artemis-1
infrastructure-artemis-1  | Creating Broker with args --role admin --name broker --allow-anonymous --http-host 172.19.0.2 --host 172.19.0.2  --force
infrastructure-artemis-1  | Cannot initialize queue:Function not implemented
infrastructure-artemis-1  |
infrastructure-artemis-1  | usage: artemis <command> [<args>]
infrastructure-artemis-1  |
infrastructure-artemis-1  | The most commonly used artemis commands are:
infrastructure-artemis-1  |     address    Address tools group (create|delete|update|show) (example ./artemis address create)
infrastructure-artemis-1  |     browser    It will browse messages on an instance
infrastructure-artemis-1  |     check      Check tools group (node|queue) (example ./artemis check node)
infrastructure-artemis-1  |     consumer   It will consume messages from an instance
infrastructure-artemis-1  |     create     creates a new broker instance
infrastructure-artemis-1  |     data       data tools group (print|recover) (example ./artemis data print)
infrastructure-artemis-1  |     help       Display help information
infrastructure-artemis-1  |     mask       mask a password and print it out
infrastructure-artemis-1  |     perf       Perf tools group (example ./artemis perf client)
infrastructure-artemis-1  |     producer   It will send messages to an instance
infrastructure-artemis-1  |     queue      Queue tools group (create|delete|update|stat|purge) (example ./artemis queue create)
infrastructure-artemis-1  |     transfer   Moves Messages from one destination towards another destination
infrastructure-artemis-1  |     version    print version information
infrastructure-artemis-1  |
infrastructure-artemis-1  | See 'artemis help <command>' for more information on a specific command.
infrastructure-artemis-1  |
infrastructure-artemis-1  | Running Broker
infrastructure-artemis-1  | /opt/amq/bin/launch.sh: line 47: /home/jboss/broker/bin/artemis: No such file or directory
infrastructure-artemis-1 exited with code 127
```

Comment: I changed ARTEMIS_USERNAME to AMQ_USER and ARTEMIS_PASSWORD to AMQ_PASSWORD and it worked for me.

Answer (score 5):

**I had to enable Rosetta** in Docker in order to make it work.

*Docker settings* → *Features in development* → check *☑ Use Rosetta for x86/amd64 emulation on Apple Silicon*, and then restart Docker.

Comment: This is the way

Answer (score 1):

Try to run with

```
  AMQ_EXTRA_ARGS: "--nio"
```

This will switch the IO to plain Java. The emulation on M1 doesn't work with the standard IO setting in the image.

Alternatively use:

```
  AMQ_EXTRA_ARGS: "--nio --host 0.0.0.0 --http-host 0.0.0.0 --relax-jolokia"
```

This will allow the console to be accessed as well, because otherwise Jolokia binds to the local address inside the container, only.

User and pw are set via:

```
  AMQ_USER: "admin"
  AMQ_PASSWORD: "admin"
```

see the image source at https://github.com/artemiscloud/activemq-artemis-broker-image/blob/main/modules/activemq-artemis-install/added/launch.sh

Answer (score 0):

Something is wrong with you docker-compose file(check network). Ican run it with simple one liner

```
docker run -e AMQ_USER=admin -e AMQ_PASSWORD=admin -p8161:8161 --name artemis quay.io/artemiscloud/activemq-artemis-broker
```

docker inspect shows(network)

```
"NetworkSettings": {
    "Bridge": "",
    "SandboxID": "fdd6c31e6e984369e592b968c7eaa465ee67233dd8d8d3d048c9fc99898089f5",
    "HairpinMode": false,
    "LinkLocalIPv6Address": "",
    "LinkLocalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
    "Ports": {
        "8080/tcp": null,
        "8161/tcp": [
            {
                "HostIp": "0.0.0.0",
                "HostPort": "8161"
            },
            {
                "HostIp": "::",
                "HostPort": "8161"
            }
        ],
        "8443/tcp": null
    },
```

By the way I am on Ubuntu.

Comment: I am having some troubles with the new M1 chip on the Mac. So need someone that is using M1. Thanks though

Comment: ```WARNING: The requested image's platform (linux/amd64) does not match the detected host platform (linux/arm64/v8) and no specific platform was requested
Creating Broker with args --user XXXXX --password XXXXX --role admin --name broker --allow-anonymous --http-host 172.17.0.2 --host 172.17.0.2   --force
Cannot initialize queue:Function not implemented ``` This is what i get

Comment: @Samovar Add this --platform linux/amd64.

Comment: Cannot initialize queue:Function not implemented

usage: artemis <command> [<args>]

See 'artemis help <command>' for more information on a specific command.

Running Broker
/opt/amq/bin/launch.sh: line 47: /home/jboss/broker/bin/artemis: No such file or directory    

Any idea about this? @Richard Rublev

Comment: No clue,not at all.

Comment: @Samovar I'm having this problem as well. After cloning a git repo with a working docker-compose file (which I assume this normally works, otherwise it would not have been merged), I got this error. I have an M1 chip as well.

Answer (score -1):

Try changing the compose HOME var to /opt/amq

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).